# difference between a repository and factory pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Can you please outline the differences between the Repository pattern and the Factory pattern?

Comment: btw, the two patterns are unrelated...

Answer (score 66):

[The Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Pattern) is for creating objects, while [the Repository pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) describes a general method of encapsulating CRUD operations against a data source.

Comment: You can also say, ...is for creating several families of objects.

Comment: So if we had needed to create a relationship between some external services and a local DbContext would designing a factory for this purpose be an efficient way to implement a factory? Then create repositories accordingly within a UOW.

Comment: Question:  Say I need to create an object instance, but I also want to *populate* that instance with fresh new data from database, aka use the "R" of CRUD while creating an object.  What is the resulting pattern called?  Is it a `Factory` that uses `Repository` as part of object creation?

Comment: If the object is filled with data from the database, then conceptually it is not a new object, because the data was already there. So I would say it's a Repository.

Answer (score 29):

The repository pattern deals with creating a set of data access services, ie. CRUD methods.
The factory pattern on the other hand deals with how an object is created.  A factory class will have a method that returns a new instance of a class.

The two are independent of each other; however, you will often see the factory pattern used alongside the repository pattern in order to create a new instance of an entity.

Answer (score 1):

**I think the difference is the usage of both.**

If you want to create objects and fill those objects with database data you will use a Repository. You can have a `CustomerRepository` with all related methods in it for retrieving and manipulation of `Customers`.

If you want to create Objects and fill those objects with data you use a Factory. An example could be a `ColorFactory`. You can fill that one with a lot of possible RGB colors that you will use later on.

If you look at something like "saving" data you could also use different words like: store, save and persist. All three are used for a different purpose while they may do the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

`->` **Factory Pattern**

The Factory Pattern is used in cases where a class cannot anticipate the type of objects it needs to create.
This pattern is used to encapsulate object creation logic and makes it easier to add new types of objects to the application without modifying the existing code.

`->` **Repository Pattern**

The Repository Pattern is a design pattern used to separate the logic that retrieves data from a data source from the business logic that processes the data.
It provides a way to centralize data access and abstracts the underlying data storage details from the business logic.